# How to convert python CPU script to runs on GPU

Tags: python, gpu, numba

How to edit a python script that runs on CPU to runs on GPU which support cuda?

here is the code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime as dt
import scipy.signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
import tqdm

def get_start(l):
    for i,line in enumerate(l):
        if 'Zeit' in line or 'Time' in line:
            return i+1

def get_meas2(l):
    index = {
        0 :'fl',
        1 :'fr',
        2 :'rl',
        3 :'rr',
        4 :'rfl',
        5 :'rfr',
        6 :'rrl',
        7 :'rrr',
    }
    res = {
        'fl'  : None ,
        'fr'  : None ,
        'rl'  : None ,
        'rr'  : None ,
        'rfl' : None ,
        'rfr' : None ,
        'rrl' : None ,
        'rrr' : None ,
        }
    res_c =res.copy()
    meas = []
    i=0
    s = get_start(l)
    for line in l[s:]:
        sp = line.split(';')
        sensor = index[int(sp[1])]
        tt = sp[0].replace(' PM','').replace(' AM','')
        t = dt.strptime (tt,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')        
        val = float(sp[2].replace(',','.'))
        if res_c[sensor]==None:
            res_c[sensor] = val 
        else:
            res_c['sample'] = i
            res_c['time'] = t
            i+=1
            for k in res_c.keys():
                if res_c[k]==None:
                    res_c[k]=0
            meas.append(res_c)
            res_c = res.copy()
            res_c[sensor] = val
    return meas

def read_csv1(filepath):
    l = open(filepath,'r',errors='backslashreplace').readlines()
    js ={
        'createdBy': None ,
        'csvFileName': None ,
        'eftFileName': None ,
        'hasCoDriver': None ,
        'hasDriver': None ,
        'measurement': None ,
        'plateHeight': None ,
        'plateLength': 600 ,
        'rating': None ,
        'recordedOn': None ,
        'remarks': None ,
        'sampleRate': 50 ,
        'vehicleChassis': None ,
        'vehicleManufacturer': None ,
        'vehicleModel': None ,
        'vehicleType': None ,
        'vehicleWheelBase': 2650 ,
        'vehicleYearOfConstruction': None ,
        'version': None ,
    }
    js['measurement'] = get_meas2(l)
    # return js
    return parse_data(js)

def parse_data(data):
        measurments = {}
        for key in data["measurement"][0].keys():
            measurments[key] = [d[key] for d in data["measurement"]]
        return measurments

def AVG2(a,n):
    windows = []
    for k,v in n.items():
        windows += [k] * v
    i=0
    res = []
    cont = True
    while cont:
        for w in windows:
            if i+w <len(a):
                res.append(np.mean(a[i:i+w]))
                i +=w
            else:
                cont = False
    return res

def findFirstRise(a):
    n = 5
    m = 20
    for i in range(len(a)-11):
        if a[i+m] >1 and a[i]!=0:
            if a[i+m]/a[i] > n:
                return i

def sync(a, window={4:10,5:1}, k=0.0065, Wn=90, fs=5000):
    # Step 1 --> under sampling
    a = [float(i) for i in a if i!='#VALUE!' and i== i]
    a = AVG2(a,window)

    #Setp 2 --> scaling
    a = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.abs(x-np.mean(a)))(a)
    # k = np.mean(GT)/np.mean(a)
    a = np.vectorize(lambda x: x*k)(a)

    #step 3 --> iir filter
    bb, aa = scipy.signal.iirfilter(1, Wn=Wn, fs=fs, btype="low", ftype="butter")
    y_lfilter = scipy.signal.lfilter(bb, aa, a)

    # y_lfilter = scipy.signal.lfilter((0.0661221,0.0661221), (1.,-0.8677558), a)
    return y_lfilter

def syncP(a,param):
    ik,iwn,ifs,i4,i5 = param
    window={4:i4,5:i5}
    k=ik
    Wn=iwn
    fs=ifs
    # Step 1 --> under sampling
    a = [float(i) for i in a if i!='#VALUE!' and i== i]
    a = AVG2(a,window)

    #Setp 2 --> scaling
    a = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.abs(x-np.mean(a)))(a)
    # k = np.mean(GT)/np.mean(a)
    a = np.vectorize(lambda x: x*k)(a)

    #step 3 --> iir filter
    bb, aa = scipy.signal.iirfilter(1, Wn=Wn, fs=fs, btype="low", ftype="butter")
    # print(bb, aa, sep="\n")
    y_lfilter = scipy.signal.lfilter(bb, aa, a)

    # y_lfilter = scipy.signal.lfilter((0.0661221,0.0661221), (1.,-0.8677558), a)
    return y_lfilter

def syncOfsset(a,sb,offset=None):
    if not offset:
        offset = findFirstRise(a) - findFirstRise(sb)
    if offset >0:
        a = a[offset:]
    else:
        sb = sb[np.abs(offset):]
    l = min(len(a),len(sb))
    return a[:l],sb[:l],(offset,l)

def findOffset(a,sb):
    return findFirstRise(a) - findFirstRise(sb)

def mae(a,sb):
    if len(a) != len(sb): raise ValueError(f'len(a)= {len(a)} while len(sb) = {len(sb)}')
    return np.abs(np.subtract(a,sb)).mean()

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from  scipy.stats import pearsonr

def getMoreThan3(a1,sb1):
    aa = []
    last=False
    for i,v in enumerate(a1):
        if v>3:
            aa.append(True)
            last=True
        else:
            if last:
                if True in [j>3 for j in a1[i:i+1]]:
                    aa.append(True)
                    last = True
                else:
                    aa.append(False)
                    last = False
            else:
                aa.append(False)
                last = False
    ca=[]
    cb=[]
    index = []
    for i,(ai,sbi,t) in enumerate(zip(a1,sb1,aa)):
        if t: 
            ca.append(ai)
            cb.append(sbi)
            index.append(i)
    return ca,cb

def check2(a,b,param):
    ik,iwn,ifs,i4,i5 = param
    sb = sync(b, window={4:i4,5:i5}, k=ik ,Wn=iwn, fs=ifs)
    a1,sb1,data = syncOfsset(a,sb)
    offset,l = data
    r2 = r2_score(a1,sb1)
    for i in range(-5,5):
        a2,sb2,data2 = syncOfsset(a,sb,offset=offset+i)
        r22 = r2_score(a2,sb2)
        if r22>r2:
            a1,sb1,data = a2,sb2,data2

    ca,cb = getMoreThan3(a1,sb1)
    return mae(ca,cb),rmse(ca,cb),r2_score(ca,cb),pearsonr(ca,cb)[0],(a,sb),data

def check(a,b,param):
    ik,iwn,ifs,i4,i5 = param
    sb = sync(b, window={4:i4,5:i5}, k=ik ,Wn=iwn, fs=ifs)
    a,sb,data = syncOfsset(a,sb)
    ca,cb = getMoreThan3(a,sb)
    return mae(ca,cb),rmse(ca,cb),r2_score(ca,cb),pearsonr(ca,cb)[0],(a,sb),data

def rmse(a,sb):
    if len(a) != len(sb): raise ValueError(f'len(a)= {len(a)} while len(sb) = {len(sb)}')
    return np.sqrt(np.square(np.subtract(a,sb)).mean())  

def analyse(i,param):
    f = f"test{i}.csv"
    d1 = read_csv1(os.path.join('sensor1',f))
    selSen = selectSensor(d1)
    d1 = d1[selSen]
    d3 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('sensor3',f))['Unnamed: 2']
    return check2(d1,d3,param),selSen

def selectSensor(a):
    s = {}
    for sensor in a:
        if len(sensor)==2:
            s[sensor] = max(a[sensor])
    return max(s,key=s.get)

def handle_process(param):
    i = 4
    (res1,res2,r2,pr, _,data),selSen = analyse(i,param)
    with open('results.csv','a') as f:
        line = str(param) + ',' + str(res1) + ',' + str(res2) + ',' +str(r2) + ',' +str(pr) + ',' +str(data) + ',' +str(selSen) + ',' + '\n'
        line = line.replace('(','').replace(')','')
        f.write(line)

if __name__=='__main__':
    base_dir1 = 'sensor1'
    base_dir3 = 'sensor3'

    rWn = range(80,100,5)
    rK = range(65,80,5)
    r4W = range(9,12,1)
    r5W = range(0,3)
    rFs = range(4000,6000,200)

    params = []
    for iWn in rWn:
        for iFs in rFs:
            for i4W in r4W:
                for i5W in r5W:
                    for ik in rK:
                        params.append((ik/10000,iWn,iFs,i4W,i5W))

    with open('results.csv','a') as f:
        line = ['k','wn','fs','window4','window5',\
                'mae(>3)','rmse(>3)','r2(>3)','pearsonr(>3)',\
                'OffsetStart','length','SelectedSensor','\n']

        f.write(','.join(line))
        f.close()

    pool = Pool(processes=8)
    for _ in tqdm.tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(handle_process, params), total=len(params)):
        pass
```

To make sure that I have the ability to run the code on the GPU, I successfully tested the sample code on my laptop and based on it, I modified my code as follows; But I am facing the following error after execution.

```
from numba import jit, cuda
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime as dt
import scipy.signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
import tqdm


def get_start(l):
    for i,line in enumerate(l):
        if 'Zeit' in line or 'Time' in line:
            return i+1

def get_meas2(l):
    index = {
        0 :'fl',
        1 :'fr',
        2 :'rl',
        3 :'rr',
        4 :'rfl',
        5 :'rfr',
        6 :'rrl',
        7 :'rrr',
    }
    res = {
        'fl'  : None ,
        'fr'  : None ,
        'rl'  : None ,
        'rr'  : None ,
        'rfl' : None ,
        'rfr' : None ,
        'rrl' : None ,
        'rrr' : None ,
        }
    res_c =res.copy()
    meas = []
    i=0
    s = get_start(l)
    for line in l[s:]:
        sp = line.split(';')
        sensor = index[int(sp[1])]
        tt = sp[0].replace(' PM','').replace(' AM','')
        t = dt.strptime (tt,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')        
        val = float(sp[2].replace(',','.'))
        if res_c[sensor]==None:
            res_c[sensor] = val 
        else:
            res_c['sample'] = i
            res_c['time'] = t
            i+=1
            for k in res_c.keys():
                if res_c[k]==None:
                    res_c[k]=0
            meas.append(res_c)
            res_c = res.copy()
            res_c[sensor] = val
    return meas

def read_csv1(filepath):
    l = open(filepath,'r',errors='backslashreplace').readlines()
    js ={
        'createdBy': None ,
        'csvFileName': None ,
        'eftFileName': None ,
        'hasCoDriver': None ,
        'hasDriver': None ,
        'measurement': None ,
        'plateHeight': None ,
        'plateLength': 600 ,
        'rating': None ,
        'recordedOn': None ,
        'remarks': None ,
        'sampleRate': 50 ,
        'vehicleChassis': None ,
        'vehicleManufacturer': None ,
        'vehicleModel': None ,
        'vehicleType': None ,
        'vehicleWheelBase': 2650 ,
        'vehicleYearOfConstruction': None ,
        'version': None ,
    }
    js['measurement'] = get_meas2(l)
    # return js
    return parse_data(js)

def parse_data(data):
        measurments = {}
        for key in data["measurement"][0].keys():
            measurments[key] = [d[key] for d in data["measurement"]]
        return measurments


def AVG2(a,n):
    windows = []
    for k,v in n.items():
        windows += [k] * v
    i=0
    res = []
    cont = True
    while cont:
        for w in windows:
            if i+w <len(a):
                res.append(np.mean(a[i:i+w]))
                i +=w
            else:
                cont = False
    return res


def findFirstRise(a):
    n = 5
    m = 20
    for i in range(len(a)-11):
        if a[i+m] >1 and a[i]!=0:
            if a[i+m]/a[i] > n:
                return i


def sync(a, window={4:10,5:1}, k=0.0065, Wn=90, fs=5000):
    # Step 1 --> under sampling
    a = [float(i) for i in a if i!='#VALUE!' and i== i]
    a = AVG2(a,window)

    #Setp 2 --> scaling
    a = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.abs(x-np.mean(a)))(a)
    # k = np.mean(GT)/np.mean(a)
    a = np.vectorize(lambda x: x*k)(a)

    #step 3 --> iir filter
    bb, aa = scipy.signal.iirfilter(1, Wn=Wn, fs=fs, btype="low", ftype="butter")
    y_lfilter = scipy.signal.lfilter(bb, aa, a)

    # y_lfilter = scipy.signal.lfilter((0.0661221,0.0661221), (1.,-0.8677558), a)
    return y_lfilter


def syncP(a,param):
    ik,iwn,ifs,i4,i5 = param
    window={4:i4,5:i5}
    k=ik
    Wn=iwn
    fs=ifs
    # Step 1 --> under sampling
    a = [float(i) for i in a if i!='#VALUE!' and i== i]
    a = AVG2(a,window)

    #Setp 2 --> scaling
    a = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.abs(x-np.mean(a)))(a)
    # k = np.mean(GT)/np.mean(a)
    a = np.vectorize(lambda x: x*k)(a)

    #step 3 --> iir filter
    bb, aa = scipy.signal.iirfilter(1, Wn=Wn, fs=fs, btype="low", ftype="butter")
    # print(bb, aa, sep="\n")
    y_lfilter = scipy.signal.lfilter(bb, aa, a)

    # y_lfilter = scipy.signal.lfilter((0.0661221,0.0661221), (1.,-0.8677558), a)
    return y_lfilter


def syncOfsset(a,sb,offset=None):
    if not offset:
        offset = findFirstRise(a) - findFirstRise(sb)
    if offset >0:
        a = a[offset:]
    else:
        sb = sb[np.abs(offset):]
    l = min(len(a),len(sb))
    return a[:l],sb[:l],(offset,l)


def findOffset(a,sb):
    return findFirstRise(a) - findFirstRise(sb)


def mae(a,sb):
    if len(a) != len(sb): raise ValueError(f'len(a)= {len(a)} while len(sb) = {len(sb)}')
    return np.abs(np.subtract(a,sb)).mean()

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from  scipy.stats import pearsonr


def getMoreThan3(a1,sb1):
    aa = []
    last=False
    for i,v in enumerate(a1):
        if v>3:
            aa.append(True)
            last=True
        else:
            if last:
                if True in [j>3 for j in a1[i:i+1]]:
                    aa.append(True)
                    last = True
                else:
                    aa.append(False)
                    last = False
            else:
                aa.append(False)
                last = False
    ca=[]
    cb=[]
    index = []
    for i,(ai,sbi,t) in enumerate(zip(a1,sb1,aa)):
        if t: 
            ca.append(ai)
            cb.append(sbi)
            index.append(i)
    return ca,cb

@jit(target_backend='cuda')
def check2(a,b,param):
    ik,iwn,ifs,i4,i5 = param
    sb = sync(b, window={4:i4,5:i5}, k=ik ,Wn=iwn, fs=ifs)
    a1,sb1,data = syncOfsset(a,sb)
    offset,l = data
    r2 = r2_score(a1,sb1)
    for i in range(-5,5):
        a2,sb2,data2 = syncOfsset(a,sb,offset=offset+i)
        r22 = r2_score(a2,sb2)
        if r22>r2:
            a1,sb1,data = a2,sb2,data2

    ca,cb = getMoreThan3(a1,sb1)
    return mae(ca,cb),rmse(ca,cb),r2_score(ca,cb),pearsonr(ca,cb)[0],(a,sb),data

@jit(target_backend='cuda')
def check(a,b,param):
    ik,iwn,ifs,i4,i5 = param
    sb = sync(b, window={4:i4,5:i5}, k=ik ,Wn=iwn, fs=ifs)
    a,sb,data = syncOfsset(a,sb)
    ca,cb = getMoreThan3(a,sb)
    return mae(ca,cb),rmse(ca,cb),r2_score(ca,cb),pearsonr(ca,cb)[0],(a,sb),data

@jit(target_backend='cuda')
def rmse(a,sb):
    if len(a) != len(sb): raise ValueError(f'len(a)= {len(a)} while len(sb) = {len(sb)}')
    return np.sqrt(np.square(np.subtract(a,sb)).mean())  

@jit(target_backend='cuda')
def analyse(i,param):
    f = f"test{i}.csv"
    d1 = read_csv1(os.path.join('sensor1',f))
    selSen = selectSensor(d1)
    d1 = d1[selSen]
    d3 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('sensor3',f))['Unnamed: 2']
    return check2(d1,d3,param),selSen

@jit(target_backend='cuda')
def selectSensor(a):
    s = {}
    for sensor in a:
        if len(sensor)==2:
            s[sensor] = max(a[sensor])
    return max(s,key=s.get)

@jit(target_backend='cuda')
def handle_process(param):
    i = 4
    (res1,res2,r2,pr, _,data),selSen = analyse(i,param)
    with open('results.csv','a') as f:
        line = str(param) + ',' + str(res1) + ',' + str(res2) + ',' +str(r2) + ',' +str(pr) + ',' +str(data) + ',' +str(selSen) + ',' + '\n'
        line = line.replace('(','').replace(')','')
        f.write(line)

if __name__=='__main__':
    base_dir1 = 'sensor1'
    base_dir3 = 'sensor3'

    rWn = range(80,100,5)
    rK = range(65,80,5)
    r4W = range(9,12,1)
    r5W = range(0,3)
    rFs = range(4000,6000,200)

    params = []
    for iWn in rWn:
        for iFs in rFs:
            for i4W in r4W:
                for i5W in r5W:
                    for ik in rK:
                        params.append((ik/10000,iWn,iFs,i4W,i5W))

    with open('results.csv','a') as f:
        line = ['k','wn','fs','window4','window5',\
                'mae(>3)','rmse(>3)','r2(>3)','pearsonr(>3)',\
                'OffsetStart','length','SelectedSensor','\n']

        f.write(','.join(line))
        f.close()

    pool = Pool(processes=1)
    for _ in tqdm.tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(handle_process, params), total=len(params)):
        pass
```

But I receive error:

```
  0%|                                                                                         | 0/1080 [00:05<?, ?it/s]
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 471, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'unsupported_error')
  File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.UnsupportedError: Failed in object mode pipeline (step: analyzing bytecode)
The 'with (context manager) as (variable):' construct is not supported.
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Amin\Downloads\AnalyseSelectSensor\analyseoneg.py", line 299, in <module>
    for _ in tqdm.tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(handle_process, params), total=len(params)):
  File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tqdm\std.py", line 1195, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 873, in next
    raise value
numba.core.errors.UnsupportedError: Failed in object mode pipeline (step: analyzing bytecode)
The 'with (context manager) as (variable):' construct is not supported.
```

Do you have any idea, how I can solve this issue?

Kind regards.

Comment: You cannot run a CPU script on a GPU! GPUs have very different architecture and cannot run most code designed for CPUs. I think adapting this code for GPUs requires a *complete rewrite* of the code. You should forget the `target_backend='cuda'` which does not work for `jit` AFAIK. In fact, even if it would, jitted functions cannot run non-jitted function anyway (and definitively never on a GPU). Ha, and using multiprocessing with a GPU code is a very bad idea by the way. GPU codes are not faster with multiple processes as they are already parallel.

Comment: Put it shortly, I strongly advise you to learn how GPUs works before trying to use them. Using GPUs here is a huge work (and I am not sure the result will be faster in the end). I think you should first focus on optimizing this on CPUs using Numba. You need to learn to walk before trying to run.

Comment: Note also that the (first pages of the) Numba documentation explicitly state that Pandas functions are not supported like most external modules. Please read the doc (more) carefully. Such issues are also covered by past answers... Finally, if you want some help, then you need to be more specific: the code needs to be much smaller and the overhead should be clearly identified.

Comment: can you share your csv files like test4.csv @yasercode find me in telegram